# Load p:graphicImage using ajax on show

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create gallery for images which uses `<p:galleryImage/>`. The problem is that when gallery contains a lot of images it download all of them and after that shows them. It is really annoying and it must work in different way. Now gallery looks like this:

```
<p:lightBox>
    <h:commandButton class="button  button-1-3 graphics-portfolio-plakaty" onclick="plakaty.show();" />
    <f:facet name="inline">
        <p:galleria value="#{galleryBean.imageNames}" var="imageName" panelWidth="800" panelHeight="500">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/gallery?img=#{imageName}" cache="false" />
        </p:galleria>
    </f:facet>
</p:lightBox>
```

I want to load images using ajax so it should look like this.

```
<p:lightBox>
    <h:commandButton class="button  button-1-3 graphics-portfolio-plakaty" onclick="plakaty.show();" />
    <f:facet name="inline">
        <p:galleria value="#{galleryBean.imageNames}" var="imageName" panelWidth="800" panelHeight="500">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/gallery?img=#{imageName}" cache="false">
                <p:ajax event="ready" />
            </p:graphicImage>
        </p:galleria>
    </f:facet>
</p:lightBox>
```

I'm new in JSF so there may be so better way to do this or how can I load image using ajax?

Comment: Try use [effect](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/effectMessages.jsf)  with event="load". See also Effect Target